# How to disable default calendar notification on Samsung Watch Active 2

Tags: samsung, calendar, samsung-galaxy-watch-active

I have the Samsung Watch Active 2, and use Google Calendar app on my phone, which also has event notifications on my watch, which is great.

However, the default Samsung calendar notification also shows up, but it would lock up the screen and require me to explicitly dismiss the notification to use the watch. Is there a way this notification can be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I opened the Samsung Calendar app on my phone. Not through device manager but the Default Calendar that comes with Samsung phones. From there you can see all calendars and un-check the calenders you do or do not want to be synced.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung calendar->settings->alert settings

Change all to none. You're welcome.